# Jersey on Spring Boot - ApplicationPath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey

Is there a more programmatic way, equivalent to the below config:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
```

, of setting the application path for Jersey app? I wanted to make it configurable and maybe make use something like:

```
property("jersey.config.<application.path>", api);
```

with addtitinal:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jersey")
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

@Setter @Getter protected String api;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `spring.jersey.application-path` config in your `application.properties`.

Comment: spring.jersey.application-path=api  or whatever your main API path. 
This will force jersey to that path only taking everything from /**.

Answer (score 0):

spring.jersey.application-path=api or whatever your main API path. This will force jersey to that path only taking everything from /**